# Tensorflow training: CPU Xeon or 2 GPU gtx750. Who is faster?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision

I use CPU xeon E5-1650 (3.2 GHz, 6Cores, 12 Threads) for training Tensorflow model.
But training is so slow...

If I will use desktop computer with typical CPU and 2 GPU GeForce GTX750 (2 Gb), it will be faster?

Answer (score -2):

Using the GPU's will be faster. The only things to keep in mind are that the size of your model is then constrained by the memory of the GPUs and that you have to choose the right sets of version numbers and drivers, such that your GPU is supported.